# Rails ActionCable - add mount ActionCable to a show path only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Does anybody know how i can specify

```
mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
```

only to a show page from a crud path? 
 Currently i have inside routes.rb:

```
resources :rooms do
    mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
end
```

which works. But i would like to limit that only to the show crud of this resource. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't from the `routes.rb` file.

You could take this the other way around: From JavaScript, connect to the ActionCable only when you're in the `show` page of the `RoomsController`.

Also from ActionCable you'd have to check where come from the connection, and reject connections from other paths than the `show` page of the `RoomsController`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Have you any snippet how to do that in Javascript? It doesn't needs to be anything that works with my example, just an showcase how to approach that, because i have no idea how to get the path down to javascript. Via ajax?

Comment: There are plenty of resource over the internet that explain how to use ActionCable from Rails and JavaScript sides like this article: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/talking-to-actioncable-without-rails. Let me know if that helps.